# tried opening some windows programs with wine, now they won't open in windows?

Tags: windows, wine, 13.04

I did try to WINE e-sword. That did not work, so I am back at Windows 7 and e-sword will not open there.

Comment: Did you open the e-sword that you had stored on your windows machine?

Comment: You have to install the Windows program within WINE. WINE has its own place to store the setup info, registry info etc. Without those most Windows programs won't work.

Comment: e-sword does work with Wine 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

The proper method of running a Windows program in Ubuntu begins with installing Wine and then installing that Windows program under Wine.

If you try and execute a program stored in the Windows disk/partition of your computer from Ubuntu, it might work for some portable/standalone programs but most Windows programs might not even start.

It's difficult to know how such a program behaves under these circumstances, but in most cases it shouldn't make any changes in the Windows disk/partition of your computer other than making some changes in your Ubuntu directory `/home/$USER/.wine`.

So it might merely be a coincidence that e-sword failed to work after you tried to run it from Ubuntu, although other possibilities cannot be ruled out completely.